# Difficulty understanding return values and function parameters in Python

Tags: python, function

I'm having a hard time understanding how return values work and how parameters can receive data. Is this close and what resources should I use to improve it? Thank you.

```
def getInfo():

    a = int(input('Please enter the first number in the range:'))
    b = int(input('Please enter then second number in the range:'))
    return a, b

def loopIt(a, b):

    for i in range(a, b):
        print('i is now {}'.format(i))

getInfo()
loopIt(a, b)
```

Comment: I guess we cannot help you as it seems you lack the basic understanding about programming itself. A better way should be reading some books for newcomers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getInfo()` will return a single *tuple* of `(a, b)`.
For example:

```
# with inputs as a = 3, b = 6
getInfo() # produces (3, 6) as a single tuple
```

To actually pull the two separate values out from the tuple, you'll need something like:

```
a, b = getInfo()
loopIt(a, b)
```

You can combine both `getInfo()` and `loopIt()` together by separating `a` and `b` from a single `data` argument inside `loopIt()`, like this:

```
def getInfo():
    a = int(input('Please enter the first number in the range:'))
    b = int(input('Please enter then second number in the range:'))
    return a, b

def loopIt(data):
    a, b = data
    for i in range(a, b):
        print('i is now {}'.format(i))

loopIt(getInfo())
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.  Now I can look at the two side by side and begin to figure something out.  I believe my confusion is with (data) in loopIt().  I expected it would need two arguments.  also, a, b =data confuses me still, but at least I now have something working to mess with. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!  Note that you can still do the two-argument `loopIt()`, as in my first example.  The basic intuition is that a function will return *one* of something.  That something may be atomic (like a single number), or it may have parts (like a tuple or a list).  If it has parts, you can assign the value of each part to separate variables.  Doing `a, b = getInfo()` is the same as doing `data = getInfo(); a = data[0]; b = data[1]`.  It's just shorthand.

Comment: This was all very helpful!  Appreciate it